# CSV read error in Python using Panda

Tags: python

I want to read a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Andy\DataScience\python\Loan_Prediction\Train.csv') 
df.head(10)
```

But getting error  as below

```
IOError: File Train.csv does not exist
```

But the file does exist in the location.

Comment: Is your path correct?

Answer (score 0):

If using backslash, because it is a special character in Python, you must remember to escape every instance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Andy\\DataScience\\python\\Loan_Prediction\\Train.csv') 
df.head(10)
```

Comment: Thanks Linas for your reply...I thought like using raw string I will not be needing the extra slash....but even with your approach it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

your read_csv could not find the path for reading the csv you have to give forward slashes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Andy/DataScience/python/Loan_Prediction/Train.csv')
```

if it again gives error then just double the slashes to avoid any special character.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C://Andy//DataScience//python//Loan_Prediction//Train.csv')

df.head(10)
```